# Visual Basic evaluate a list of cards for a straight combination

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, poker

I'm creating a Poker evaluater, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to check for "straight" combinations (I also need to know what cards made the combination).

I have a list of cards, so what I need to figure out is the following:

Does the list contain an ace or not?

If yes:

- Create a new list where ace is high.
- Create a new list where ace is low.
- Run check on both lists and return whichever has the higher count of cards that are in a straight combination.

If No:

- Run check on list and return the cards that are in a straight combination.

How to check for a straight combination:

Run through the list and check whether the current card's rank + 1 is equal to the previous card's rank.

Using this method we will run into an issue....

Take the following into consideration:

1. King
2. Queen
3. Jack
4. Three
5. Two

The result would be:

1. King = Nothing = False
2. Queen = King = True
3. Jack = Queen = True
4. Three = Jack = False
5. Two = Three = True

That result is no good, the result in that case should be: King, Queen, Jack.

I'm not sure how to put this into code in a smart way, or just in a way that would work. I have tried doing LINQ and I have tried using for loops.

Here's the card class that I have made:

```
Public Enum CardRank
    Two = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
    Five = 5
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Jack = 11
    Queen = 12
    King = 13
    Ace = 14
End Enum

Public Enum CardSuit
    Club = 1
    Diamond = 2
    Heart = 3
    Spade = 4
End Enum

Public Class Card
    Public Rank As CardRank
    Public Suit As CardSuit

#Region "Constructor"
    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Sub New(ByVal Rank As CardRank, ByVal Suit As CardSuit)
        Me.Rank = Rank
        Me.Suit = Suit
    End Sub
#End Region

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return [Enum].GetName(GetType(CardRank), Rank) + " of " + [Enum].GetName(GetType(CardSuit), Suit)
    End Function
End Class
```

Copy this to quickly get started:

```
Dim Deck As New List(Of Card)
Dim Cards As List(Of Card) = New Card() {New Card(CardRank.King, CardSuit.Spade), New Card(CardRank.Queen, CardSuit.Heart), New Card(CardRank.Jack, CardSuit.Club), New Card(CardRank.Three, CardSuit.Spade), New Card(CardRank.Two, CardSuit.Diamond)}.ToList()

'Add deck
For Each Suit As CardSuit In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(CardSuit))
    For Each Rank As CardRank In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(CardRank))
        Deck.Add(New Card(Rank, Suit))
    Next
Next

For Each Card As Card In Cards
    Deck.Remove(Card)
Next
```

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

EDIT: A straight is five cards of sequential rank. Note that in holdem, Aces can be high or low.
EDIT: Here's how I list my cards atm. (Can be altered to fit other methods of course)

```
Dim tempList = Cards.GroupBy(Function(card) card.Rank).Reverse().OrderByDescending(Function(group) group.Count()).SelectMany(Function(group) group).ToList()
```

Comment: Your code shows your classes, but not how you have attempted to rank them. Do you have some more code to show?

Comment: I have edited my main post, please take another look. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank everybody who offered their time and help, this was a problem that I had been struggling with for days!

In the end I figured it out myself. My method of doing it covers every possibility, not just some, and it also returns the list of cards that created the combination.

The base function:

```
    Private Function ReturnStraight(ByVal tempList As List(Of Card)) As List(Of Card)
    Dim cardslist As New List(Of List(Of Card)) 'Lists of lists of cards in sequential rank
    Dim temporaryList As New List(Of Card) 'Temporary list to add seqeuntial ranked cards to, to later add to the above list
    Dim previousCard As Card = tempList(0) 'Gotta start somewhere

    For i = 0 To tempList.Count - 1
        Dim Card As Card = tempList(i)

        If Card.Rank + 1 = previousCard.Rank Then 'If the queen + 1 equals king
            If temporaryList.Find(Function(c) c.Rank = previousCard.Rank) Is Nothing Then : temporaryList.Add(previousCard) : End If 'If it doesn't already contain the previous card, add it (we want the king, which we wouldn't get without this)
            temporaryList.Add(Card) 'Add the card (the queen)

            If i = tempList.Count - 1 Then 'We need this if because of certain scenarios, e.g. King, Queen, Jack, Three, Two - King, Queen, Jack would be added, but three and two would not because we would not enter the else below when Two + 1 = 3...
                If temporaryList.Count > 0 Then : cardslist.Add(temporaryList) : End If 'If the list is not empty, add it to the list of list of cards
                temporaryList = New List(Of Card) 'Assign it a new empty list of cards to elimate referencing
            End If
        Else 'If the sequential list breaks (goes from jack to 3), add the temporary list of cards to the list of list of cards
            If temporaryList.Count > 0 Then : cardslist.Add(temporaryList) : End If  'If the list is not empty, add it to the list of list of cards
            temporaryList = New List(Of Card) 'Assign it a new empty list of cards to elimate referencing
        End If

        previousCard = Card 'Assign the current card to the previousCard holder
    Next

    cardslist = cardslist.OrderByDescending(Function(list) list.Count()).ToList() 'We want to list them in descending order by the count of cards

    If Not cardslist.Count = 0 Then 'We have to check to see if the cardlist is empty or not, because if it is and we return it, we get an error.... 
        Return cardslist(0) 'Return the highest count card list
    End If

    Return tempList 'Function failed because there are not enough cards, so return the original list
End Function
```

How I am using it:

```
    Dim tempList = Cards.GroupBy(Function(card) card.Rank).OrderByDescending(Function(group) group.Count()).SelectMany(Function(group) group).ToList()

    If tempList.Find(Function(Card) Card.Rank = CardRank.Ace) IsNot Nothing Then 'We have an ace
        Dim noAce = (From Card As Card In tempList Where Card.Rank <> CardRank.Ace Select Card).ToList()
        Dim lst = ReturnStraight(noAce)
        If lst(lst.Count - 1).Rank = CardRank.Two Or lst(0).Rank = CardRank.King Then
            lst.Add((From Card As Card In tempList Where Card.Rank = CardRank.Ace Select Card).ToList(0))
        End If
    Else

        Dim lst = ReturnStraight(tempList)
        For Each Card As Card In lst
            MsgBox(Card.ToString())
        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is find the minimum and maximum card and use the sum to check if it is a straight. Pseudo code:

```
def isStraight(cards)
    isStraight = true;

    // Check for cases except ace has value 1.
    min = cards.min()
    for (index = min + 1; index < min + 5; index++)
        isStraight &= cards.exist(index);

    if not isStraight:
       // Check for case ace has value 1
       isStraight = cards.exist(14) and
                    cards.exist(2) and 
                    cards.exist(3) and 
                    cards.exist(4) and
                    cards.exist(5)

    return isStraight
```

Comment: Doesn't this ignore the existence of suits? E.g. a hand composed of 4H + 4S + 6D + 8C + 8H. Min = 4, Max = 8, (Min + Max) * 5 / 2 = 30. Sum = 30. But no straight.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are fully right; I changed the algorithm.

Comment: I think you need to `&=` or insert some early breaks in those loops. Same hand again ends up assigning `isStraight` the values `true, false, true, false, true` and then returns true.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever True .. and fixed (hard to do without a compiler nearby and test case.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Not trivial, but here's how I would tackle it.

Firstly, update your face values as follows:

```
Public Enum CardRank
    Ace = 0
    Two = 1
    Three = 2
    Four = 3
    Five = 4
    Six = 5
    Seven = 6
    Eight = 7
    Nine = 8
    Ten = 9
    Jack = 10
    Queen = 11
    King = 12
End Enum
```

So your values run from 0 for Ace to 12 for King. In many cases, you'll find your life gets easier if you get used to 0-based indexing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)

Now, if you have the cards in ascending order it's pretty easy to figure out if you have a straight. (I haven't written VB in years, so this will be pseudocode)

```
Integer card = rank of first card
//Check each of the following cards
For i = 2 to 5
    Integer nextCard = rank of next card
    If (nextCard != (card + 1) mod 13) return false
    card = nextCard
End For
```

Since we mod by 13, the card after King will be (12 + 1) mod 13 = 13 mod 13 = 0, which is the Ace, as expected.

I don't really know poker, so I'm not sure if a straight can wrap around through ace (meaning is Q, K, A, 2, 3 a straight?). If not, then it's still pretty easy to check for the two cases of aces high and aces low. Aces low is trivial, it is this code. For aces high, it has to start at 10. After sorting, the Ace will be the first card (which is not ideal) so any sequence starting [Ace, 10, ...] can be quickly re arranged as [10, ..., Ace] and then run through the same algorithm.

M